# Are .d.ts files strictly for type implementations?

Tags: typescript

Are typescript .d.ts files strictly for types?  In other words no constants or actual function implementations should exist in these files?

Comment: [yes](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html)

Comment: `d.ts` files are only for types. Actual constants and function implementations will be inside your `js` file if types are for your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `*.d.ts` files are places to hold ambient declarations. i.e. type definition without actual code that describes the runtime environment.