# How can I get intelisence in vs code for the Livechat SDK using angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, livechat

Im trying to use this NPM package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@livechat/chat-sdk

I've installed it by using:

```
yarn add @livechat/chat-sdk
```

I've also included the types by doing:

```
yarn add @types/@livechat/chat-sdk
```

I'm importing it to my project by doing:

```
import LiveChat from '@livechat/chat-sdk';
```

but when I try to use it in my project I don't get any intelesence from VS Code. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately LiveChat SDK does not provide any [definition file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463990/what-are-d-ts-files-for) (.d.ts) and/or [JSDoc](https://medium.com/@trukrs/type-safe-javascript-with-jsdoc-7a2a63209b76) in the source file so Intellisense cannot "*guess*" the correct type.

You can try adding custom type definitions by hand, see [this](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-solutions/typescript-adding-custom-type-definitions-for-existing-libraries/) article.

PS: The development dependency *@types/@livechat/chat-sdk* is not a valid package name and so does not exists :(

PS.PS: I suggest you to write the *.d.ts* file since is good for learning and create a pull request or contact a collaborator for merging the changes.

Comment: Thank you! You are amazing.